# JQGRID Frozen columns - Duplicando informações

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid

Estou utilizando a opção frozen column, como está na documentação, da seguinte forma:

```
 jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
       url:urllst,
       datatype: 'json',
       height: 'auto',
       width: 'auto',
       ignoreCase: true,
            colNames:['UF','Macro região','Região','Cód.Municipio','Nome','População','Cód.Status','Cód.Perfil','Partido Prefeito','Partido Vice','Ativo ?' ],   // PONTO DE ALTERAÇÃO
            colModel:[ // PONTO DE ALTERAÇÃO
                {name:"uf",index:"uf", width:100, sorttype:'text', viewable: true, frozen: true,
                    stype:'text',
                    formoptions:{elmprefix:'*', label: 'UF:', rowpos:1, colpos:1},
                    editable:true,
                    editrules: {required: true},
                    edittype: 'custom',
                    classes: 'c',
                    editoptions: {style: "text-transform: uppercase",
                        'custom_element' : macro_uf_element,
                        'custom_value'   : macro_uf_value,
                    },
                    searchoptions: {
                        sopt:['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','in','ni','ew','en','cn','nc']
                    }
                },
```

e logo depois:

```
rowNum:11,
rowList:[10,20,30],
caption: "Frozen Header",
shrinkToFit: false,
jQuery(#TABELA).jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
```

O "congelamento" funciona, porém os dados ficam duplicados, um por cima do outro na rolagem, então defini background com css, funciona porém nesse caso o hover e selection não funcionam nas colunas congeladas.

Foto: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você já consegui resolver?

Comment: Na verdade não, já tentei varias coisas, defini cor pelo css, pelo próprio js, nesse caso o problema da transparência se resolve, como coloquei na questão, o problema que a seleção e hover padrão do jqgrid não funcionam nas colunas com frozen. Tentei criar classe para as 4 colunas e a chamada do css funciona quando o mouse está sobre elas mas quando saio dessas 4 colunas para de novo, perdi o dia nisso.

Comment: Estou dizendo em relação a essa pergunta ta duplicando? (obs eu já vi a sua outra pergunta ai a tente resolver em outro momento ou outro op) continua repetindo, tem como editar e colocar uma imagem na sua questão, qual linguagem serve-side você usa?

Comment: Vou tirar um print, sim sobre a que está duplicando, assim estou usando jqgrid, então javascript e jquery o que percebi é que quando coloco a opção frozem o que ele faz é um tipo de copia e coloca sobreposto a coluna so que a tabela é transparente por isso aparecem as informações, quando defino a cor esse problema some, vou colocar os prints.

Comment: Pessoal ainda estou com esse problema, alguém sabe como ajudar?

Comment: Desculpe @RafaelTheodoro não visualizei erro na tela, tem como marcá-lo, pois pelo jqgrid você fez correto o frozen, da mesma maneira que utilizo, mas eu faço o seguinte, a coluna frozen são sempre as primeiras

Comment: @cavalsilva, eu coloquei a opação de frozen nas 4 primeiras colunas, olhe como os escritos ficam nela, e como se tivesse "escrito" por duas vezes, e realmente está, na segunda foto faço a rolagem e pode observar que está tudo duplicado, na segunda linha MARCRO | REGIAO tem como registro QQ, observe que aparece quatro vezes.
Foi ai que percebi que o frozen faz um tipo de copia dos dados e a jqgrid está como padrão transparente.
E quando defino cor as opções de "hover" e "select" não funcionam nas colunas "coloridas".

Comment: Exibe também o resultado do JSON ou do XML. Obg.

Comment: @cavalsilva hãn??

Comment: como você retorna o resultado? Como povoa a grid? Eu chamo o banco de dados que me retorna um JSON que preenche a grid. Isso que gostaria de ver.

Comment: Eu faço da mesma forma, BD e JSON

Comment: Entendi, mas coloque os colmodel que você configurou e o json do resultado para ver se consigo ver algo.