# Como fazer um efeito HOVER alterar outro "objeto" selecionado no jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

Tenho duas classes A e B, preciso que quando passe o mouse sobre A o que mude seja o valor, cor etc de B.
Não sei se posso fazer isso em CSS ou usando Onmouseover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vamos lá vou dar um exemplo

```
<style>
    .azul{color: blue;}
</style>

<script>
    $('#a').hover(function(){
        $('#b').toggleClass('azul'); // muda a cor do texto em B quando A estiver hover
        $('#b').text('novoValor'); // muda o valor de B quando A estiver hover
    });
</script>
```

Fiz um aqui p/ você testar http://jsfiddle.net/sneeps_ninja/FyY7D/

Comment: Maison infelizmente nesse caso não deu certo, acho que porque estou com um baita problema, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23290/jqgrid-frozen-columns-duplicando-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es.
De qualquer forma sua resposta foi muito clara e de fato é a resposta para o que eu perguntei, obrigado!